# Android 4.4.2 Intel (x86)-based emulator snapshot broken on Windows 7 x64: NAND: nand_dev_load_disk_state ftruncate failed: Invalid argument

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When I try to load the Android 4.4.2 Intel-based AVD from snapshot, like so:

[image: img1]

It freezes, and the AVD manager shows the following exception:

[image: img2]

This is my AVD configuration:

[image: img3]

My OS: Windows 7 Pro x64 SP1, running on MacBook Pro late 2011 '15 (via Boot Camp)

**Both 4.3 and 4.2 AVD snapshots work without problems.**

I am using [HAXM 1.0.6 (R3)](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) for [Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration).

Any help on how to make the snapshot work is appreciated, including hints were I can find more help :)

Comment: A lot of us on our team have the same issues with 4.4.2 Intel emulator, and we are using 2013 MBP Retinas.  None of us use 4.4.2, unfortunately and have to use a real device to do anything useful with it.